# document_missing_exception while performing ElasticSearch update

Tags: elasticsearch

I went through several questions with the same "document_missing_exception" problem but looks like they aren't the same problem in my case. I can query the document, but failed when I tried to updated it.
My query:

```
# search AuthEvent by sessionID
GET events-*/_search
{
  "size": "100",
  "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [{
                  "term": {
                      "type": {
                          "value": "AuthEvent"
                      }
                  }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "client.sessionID.raw": {
                    "value": "067d660a1504Y67FOuiiRIEkVNG8uYIlnK87liuZGLBcSmEW0aHoDXAHfu"
                  }
                }
              }
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

Query result:

```
{
  "took" : 18,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 76,
    "successful" : 76,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 6.705622,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "events-2020.10.06",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "2c675295b27a225ce243d2f13701b14222074eaf",
        "_score" : 6.705622,
        "_routing" : "067d660a1504Y67FOuiiRIEkVNG8uYIlnK87liuZGLBcSmEW0aHoDXAHfu",
        "_source" : {
          # some data
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Update request:

```
POST events-2020.10.06/_doc/2c675295b27a225ce243d2f13701b14222074eaf/_update
{
  "doc" : {
    "custom" : {
      "testField" : "testData"
    }
  }
}
```

And update result:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "document_missing_exception",
        "reason" : "[_doc][2c675295b27a225ce243d2f13701b14222074eaf]: document missing",
        "index_uuid" : "5zhQy6W6RnWscDz7Av4_bA",
        "shard" : "1",
        "index" : "events-2020.10.06"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "document_missing_exception",
    "reason" : "[_doc][2c675295b27a225ce243d2f13701b14222074eaf]: document missing",
    "index_uuid" : "5zhQy6W6RnWscDz7Av4_bA",
    "shard" : "1",
    "index" : "events-2020.10.06"
  },
  "status" : 404
}
```

I'm quite new to ElasticSearch and couldn't find any reason for such behaviour. I use ElasticSearch 6.7.1 oss version + Kibana for operating with data. I also tried with bulk update but ended with same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the query results, your document has been indexed with a  `routing` value and you're missing it in your update request.

Try this instead:

```
POST events-2020.10.06/_doc/2c675295b27a225ce243d2f13701b14222074eaf/_update?routing=067d660a1504Y67FOuiiRIEkVNG8uYIlnK87liuZGLBcSmEW0aHoDXAHfu
{
  "doc" : {
    "custom" : {
      "testField" : "testData"
    }
  }
}
```

If a document is indexed with a [`routing` value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-routing), all subsequent get, update and delete operations need to happen with that routing value as well.

Comment: That worked great! I updated the bulk update command and it worked as well. Thank you very much.